# Heroku isn't play the music even I installed ffmpeg

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

Here's my problem
I wanted to host my discord bot written in python hosted in heroku before it hosted in repl.it it work fine though, and then when I host to heroku I INSTALLED everything I need to work and look like it don't play sound.... No errors... No warnings....
Here's my github repository if you want to take a look inside ;)
[Miraculous bot github repository!](https://github.com/dumb-stuff/Music-bot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play music at Heroku mostly 2 buildpacks are necessary. These can be added to the corresponding app under `Settings`. The following buildpacks are needed:

1. https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest
2. https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus

Only then the bot will probably play music, because Heroku has its problems with FFMPEG. After you have added these two buildpacks you can select `Deploy Branch` under the category `Deploy`.

*Of course you should also add a buildpack for your system (Python, JS, etc.)*.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong Heroku doesn't supports it. So you can't run a music bot on Heroku but it should be for different types of bots Hope it helps