# error on Heroku application log after deployment

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg, discord, youtube-dl

I had made a discord bot and deploy it to Heroku in this bot I can play youtube songs normally but after deploying on Heroku it gives me errors on application logs when I am trying to play my song

**My code:-**

```
import discord,requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4
import youtube_dl
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import ffmpeg
from discord.ext import *
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient
import asyncio
@client.command(pass_context=True)                      #====================================Join
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
@client.command()                                         #==================================Play
async def play(ctx, url:str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
            player.clear()
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the current playing music end or use the 'stop' command...")
        return
    await ctx.send("Getting everything ready, playing audio soon, depends on your internet speed...")
    print("Someone wants to play music let me get that ready for them...")
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
    
    voice.volume = 100
```

It works properly on localhost from vscode

but when I trying to use this after deployment on Heroku it gives me the error below

```
2021-06-30T07:41:09.476383+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-06-30T07:41:09.476384+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2021-06-30T07:41:09.476384+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-30T07:41:09.476422+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
2021-06-30T07:41:09.476423+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
2021-06-30T07:41:09.476427+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
2021-06-30T07:41:09.476427+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2021-06-30T07:41:09.476451+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
2021-06-30T07:41:09.476452+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
2021-06-30T07:41:09.476487+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one.
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Have you added FFMPEG to the buildpacks?

Comment: Yes, I had added. You can see my files on this link   https://github.com/SohamDasBiswas/Arsenal-discord-bot

Comment: These are not the build packs. You have to use FFFMPEG from GitHub and then add it under `Settings` -> `Buildpacks`. Can you give me a link to the FFMPEG you added?

Comment: i have download ffmpeg from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: now how i set it to buildpack?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66854575/heroku-isnt-play-the-music-even-i-installed-ffmpeg/66897345#66897345