# discord.py Heroku FFmpeg issue

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, discord.py

hi I'm trying to deploy a discord bot on heroku. i'm using **ffmpeg** to stream music to a voice channel. i tried it local on my windows and got it working but when I deployed it on heroku, throws this exception and says nothing!

I use these buildpacks:

1. heroku/python
2. https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git

I appreciate if someone can help
here's a sample code:

```
vid = pafy.new("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdL7s0kw0SM")
print("Pafy Vid Created!")
audio = vid.getbestaudio()
print("Pafy Audio Created!")
try:
    // self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    self.vc[ctx.guild.id].play(FFmpegPCMAudio(Song['source'], **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda _: E.set())
    print("Playing Music!!!")
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

and here's what I got:

```
2021-09-20T14:31:19.958645+00:00 app[worker.1]: Pafy Vid Created!
2021-09-20T14:31:19.958889+00:00 app[worker.1]: Pafy Audio Created!
2021-09-20T14:31:20.447278+00:00 app[worker.1]:
```

Comment: Is this helping you? [Heroku isn't play the music even I installed ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66854575/heroku-isnt-play-the-music-even-i-installed-ffmpeg/66897345#66897345)

Comment: thank you so much. it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Dominik I added the buildpacks bellow and it worked:
1.https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus
2.https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git